# org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Доступ запрещен

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-security, postman

Разрабатываю авторизацию на сайте с помощью JWT-токенов: передача access токена и его валидация выполняются без ошибок в Postman,
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
но при попытке установить нужный HTTP-header в браузере

```
       function sendHello() {
            let res_token = $('.res').text()
            fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/hello/user', {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: new Headers({
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + res_token,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                })
            });
        }
```

```
     @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http                       
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        authz -> authz
                                .requestMatchers("/person/auth/login", "/person/auth/token", "/auth").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                                .and()
                                .addFilterAfter(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                ).build();
    }
```

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('USER')")
    @GetMapping("hello/user")
    public ResponseEntity<String> helloUser() {
        final JwtAuthentication authInfo = authService.getAuthInfo();
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello user " + authInfo.getPrincipal() + "!");
    }
```

появляется ошибка:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Access Denied
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Доступ запрещен
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:77)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть причина отказа в авторизации?

Comment: Зачем добавлена запятая после `Bearer, `, попробуйте без нее. В postman есть значек `</>` справа вверху, он показывает как реально выполняется запрос (кроме авто сгенерированных заголовков), можно смотреть на него и сравнивать с запросами отправленными браузером.

Comment: @MrFylypenko, к сожалению сервер выдает ошибку. Результат выполнения запроса в Postman: `--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhbnRvbiIsImV4cCI6MTY5MzIyNzM4MSwicm9sZXMiOlsiVVNFUiJdLCJmaXJzdE5hbWUiOiLQkNC90YLQvtC9In0.s3drUolTZ1655iX7j3U4ecdqAZpID1YIlfwDG5_0xbXE7M7m8HjahSbT3-AszR9vbvrUxhpYIqFQjUQEPgCtyw'`

Comment: Какие параметры запроса в консоли браузера (вкладка Сеть)?  уходит правильный заголовок?

Comment: @MrFylypenko, Параметр Authorization отсутствует

Comment: Скорее всего у Вас кроссдоменные запросы(фронтенд на другом порту, напр. 3000), либо запрещено передавать заголовки. Попробуйте [разрешить их как указано в этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41076561/6752984) Это безопасность браузера так настроена, если бекенд явно не разрешил заголовки, то и нельзя их отправить.

Comment: @MrFylypenko, вы мне помогли! Статус 200!